# Symfony's security cookbook yml example does not secure login_check behind firewall

Tags: security, authentication, symfony, configuration, routes

I try the symfony cookbook and specially try the security chapter. My security.yml and routing.yml are as follows:

**security.yml:**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: false

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: AcmeUserBundle:User, property: email }

    firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern: ^/login
            anonymous: ~
        register_area:
            pattern: ^/register
            anonymous: ~
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**routing.yml:**

```
login:
    pattern: /login
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeUserBundle:Account:login }
login_check:
    pattern: /login_check
```

Everything works fine, except that `login_check` says that the controller could not be found. That is exactly what the pitfall no. 3 says here: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-common-pitfalls

So I am not sure what I have done wrong. I know there are similar questions on Stackoverflow but I couldn't understand their solution and it didn't work for me, sry. Why is `login_check` not behind a firewall? I thought it would be behind `secured_area` because the pattern is `^/` and this clearly matches `/login_check`.

Question for my understanding: What does `anonymous ~` exactly do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out myself.

**security.yml:**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: false

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: AcmeUserBundle:User, property: email }

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

As `secured_area` already has an `anonymous: ~` there is no need to declare extra firewalls for `login` and `register`.

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is in FOSUSerBundle
There is fake action in controller

Comment: Sry, this has nothing to do with FOSUserBundle. I don't use it.